# Error not loading dependencies in Android Studio Test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

I have installed android studio and all the SDK needed, also connected my phone via USB in debugging mode all is good.
Now I want to run automatic tests on a app from my phone using android studio but I have many loading errors.

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
```

Espresso
ViewActions
ViewMaatchers
AAndroidJUnit4
LargeTest
rule

All can't be loaded.
My build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
```

}

Please help me understand why nothing works to fix it. I searched for info on android studio, other StackOverflow posts nothing works.

Comment: *I have many loading errors.* - show them :)